# ROS cannot find Boost header files

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Ubunti 18.04 with ROS Melodic. I was installing ROSPlan and while doing that I get errors related to Boost Headers. The output of `catkin build` is as follows,

```
catkin build --cmake-args \         
            -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
            -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
            -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m \
            -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /opt/ros/melodic:/usr0/home/vparimi/anaconda3:/usr0/home/vparimi/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr
Workspace:                   /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:        [exists] /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/install
Log Space:         [missing] /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.

NOTE: Forcing CMake to run for each package.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '8' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                                                                                                              
[build] Updating package table.                                                                                                                                         
Starting  >>> catkin_tools_prebuild                                                                                                                                     
Finished  <<< catkin_tools_prebuild                    [ 1.1 seconds ]                                                                                                  
Starting  >>> rosplan_dispatch_msgs                                                                                                                                     
Starting  >>> rosplan_knowledge_msgs                                                                                                                                    
Starting  >>> rosplan_rqt                                                                                                                                               
Starting  >>> rosplan_sensing_interface                                                                                                                                 
Finished  <<< rosplan_sensing_interface                [ 1.5 seconds ]                                                                                                  
Finished  <<< rosplan_rqt                              [ 1.8 seconds ]                                                                                                  
Finished  <<< rosplan_knowledge_msgs                   [ 7.9 seconds ]                                                                                                  
Starting  >>> rosplan_dependencies                                                                                                                                      
Finished  <<< rosplan_dispatch_msgs                    [ 7.9 seconds ]                                                                                                  
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Errors     << rosplan_dependencies:make /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/logs/rosplan_dependencies/build.make.000.log                 
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/serialization.h:34:0,
                 from /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/devel/.private/rosplan_knowledge_msgs/include/rosplan_knowledge_msgs/KnowledgeItem.h:14,
                 from /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/src/rosplan/rosplan_dependencies/ippc_server/include/rosplan_dependencies/ippc_server.h:35,
                 from /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/src/rosplan/rosplan_dependencies/ippc_server/src/ippc_server.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/time.h:58:10: fatal error: boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ippc_server.dir/ippc_server/src/ippc_server.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ippc_server.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [all] Error 2
cd /usr0/home/vparimi/Work/Research/software/github/ROSPlan/build/rosplan_dependencies; catkin build --get-env rosplan_dependencies | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=3,4 -j; cd -
........................................................................................................................................................................
Failed     << rosplan_dependencies:make                [ Exited with code 2 ]                                                                                           
Failed    <<< rosplan_dependencies                     [ 10.2 seconds ]                                                                                                 
Abandoned <<< rosplan_knowledge_base                   [ Unrelated job failed ]                                                                                         
Abandoned <<< rosplan_planning_system                  [ Unrelated job failed ]                                                                                         
[build] Summary: 5 of 8 packages succeeded.                                                                                                                             
[build]   Ignored:   1 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.                                                                                                        
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                                                                                                              
[build]   Abandoned: 2 packages were abandoned.                                                                                                                         
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                                                                                                                 
[build] Runtime: 19.3 seconds total.                                                                                                                                    
[build] Note: Workspace packages have changed, please re-source setup files to use them.
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True debug=False>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/trollius/base_events.py", line 395, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/trollius/unix_events.py", line 65, in close
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/trollius/unix_events.py", line 166, in remove_signal_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
TypeError: signal handler must be signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL, or a callable object
```

The `boost` headers are there inside `/usr/include/boost` and `cmake` does seem to find them but for some reason while building, it can't find the headers. I am confused as to why this is happening and any help regarding this is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350802/ros-cannot-find-boost-header-files/) by [viraj96](https://answers.ros.org/users/54089/viraj96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve the problem. The main issue was caused by using condo compilers. After forcing CMake to use the system compiler(gcc/g++), the linking issues were resolved.

---

Originally posted by [viraj96](https://answers.ros.org/users/54089/viraj96/) with karma: 16 on 2020-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0